# Avoid sudo password /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

Tags: sudo

How can I avoid 'sudo' in this command?

```
ssh -t root@$machine -x "sshpass -p 'ubuntu' ssh -t ubuntu@$address -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/nul  -x 'sudo mv 00proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two ways to avoid sudo in the (sub)-command:

```
ssh -t ubuntu@$address -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/nul  -x 'sudo mv 00proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'
```

Would be to either log in as `root` instead of `ubuntu`, or (I really don't recommend this) change the permissions on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` with something like `chmod a+w /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`"

Comment: i find another solution: vim /etc/sudoers

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL                                                                                                           when i use sudo mycommand it works without password but when i use ssh ..'sudo..' it doesnt work ! Have you an idea ? why it doesn't work with ssh ?